# ACF Date Picker field with Gravity Form ACF Post Creation

Tags: wordpress, date, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields, gravityforms

I have a custom post type called Events.

I used advance Post Creation Add-on and mapped all the fields to ACF. Everything seems to work and all the fields were perfectly mapped on the posts. However, there is a minor issue.

I have a Date Picker field on the ACF with display and returning format of m/d/y which was mapped on the date field of the form with the same format mm/dd/yyyy. After submission, the field displays correct format however when displayed on the wordpress pages, it changes it’s format to yyyy-mm-dd.

When I changed the Date Picker field on ACF to Text, it displays this format as well - yyyy-mm-dd but the form was set to mm/dd/yyyy. The goal is to display it on mm/dd/yyyy format.

Does anyone knows the logic behind it?

Below are the screenshots.

[image]